# Swift AVAssetDownloadURLSession won't start

Tags: swift, download, avfoundation, m3u8, urlsession

```
let background = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "AAPL-Identifier")

var assetDownloadURLSession = AVAssetDownloadURLSession(configuration: background, assetDownloadDelegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: "https://bitmovin-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s-fmp4/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa_video_180_250000.m3u8")!)
guard let task = assetDownloadURLSession.aggregateAssetDownloadTask(with: urlAsset, mediaSelections: [urlAsset.preferredMediaSelection], assetTitle: "Testing", assetArtworkData: nil, options:[AVAssetDownloadTaskMinimumRequiredMediaBitrateKey: 265_000]) else { return }

task.resume()

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, aggregateAssetDownloadTask: AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask, didLoad timeRange: CMTimeRange, totalTimeRangesLoaded loadedTimeRanges: [NSValue], timeRangeExpectedToLoad: CMTimeRange, for mediaSelection: AVMediaSelection) {
    print("start download")
}
```

I'm using the official [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/using_avfoundation_to_play_and_persist_http_live_streams), it's working fine.

but when I try to create my new sample, the AVAssetDownloadDelegate never fire...

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Are you running it on a simulator?

Comment: no on my iPhone, the official sample is working...

Comment: What about `func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)`?

Comment: I add the didCompleteWithError, but nothing happen...

Comment: Try to call `aggregateAssetDownloadTask` with `options:nil`.

Comment: Are you using `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`?

Comment: aggregateAssetDownloadTask with options:nil is not working

Comment: I try to remove the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in plist of the official sample code, and the sample code still can download the m3u8 files\

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this? I'm running into the same issue.